# Need help creating dynamic Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

**Part One:**
I'm trying to figure out how to use the DOM and Javascript to create an array containing the links in multiple lists.
The problem is I need each UL to have a unique array containing the links; the only unique ID I am able
to use in this case is the name value in the link tags. I will not be able to add anything else to the markup. 
The javascript reference will need to be contained in a single script, with one reference to the script at the 
bottom of the page.

**Part Two:**
What I ultimately need to do, is to hide each of the lists, and replace them with just the first two links,
along with a "view all" link below the two links that, when clicked, adds the other two links to the list.

Again, I can't add any markup, divs, etc. etc.; it must be completely based on the information below, the DOM and 
javascript.

Thanks for any help y'all can provide!

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="obj_a">Section One, Article One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="obj_b">Section One, Article Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="obj_c">Section One, Article Three</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="obj_d">Section One, Article Four</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="obj_e">Section Two, Article One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="obj_f">Section Two, Article Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="obj_g">Section Two, Article Three</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="obj_h">Section Two, Article Four</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's good that you have a clear [Software Requirements Document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Requirements_Specification). What have you done?

Comment: Regarding the ultimate goal described in part two (good you mentioned it): I wouldn't do this using arrays of lists, described in part one. If you can't change the markup, I would dynamically add a class to all list items, except the first two, e.g. `.extra-item`, etc., and add a button/span/whatever with an onclick-event, that toggles the class name of the `ul`, e.g. to `.invisible`. If you add `.invisible .extra-item { display: none }` to your CSS, all items except the first two will be hidden or revealed when clicking the toggle button/span/whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I am using jQuery for my solutions ;)

**Part One:**

```
var list = new Array();
$.each($('ul'), function(index, value) {
  list.push(new Array());
  $.each($(value).find('li a'), function(index2, value2){
    list[list.length - 1].push(value2.href);
  });
});
```

**Part Two:**

I really don't understand the requirements, but have a look at jQuery it really makes those takes easy.

Comment: It sounds like a Javascript library isn't an option, due to the requirement of "the javascript reference will need to be contained in a single script."  Is this the case, OP?

Comment: You can add a JS-Library in the script, where's the problem, you don't need to put jQuery in another file.

Comment: Negatory; I do have access to the yahoo YUI library but not jQuery in this case.

I think Marcel's idea above might work splendidly though.

Comment: The basic algorithm is still the same. It's just more verbose using all the standard functions rather than jQuery's convenience utilities.

Comment: Also, with jQuery, the above can be more concisely written as something like `$("ul:has(li>a)").map(function (item) { return $(item).find("a").filter(function (index) { return index < 2; }) })`. As it is, you're reinventing the `map` and `filter` functions.